# How do you keep Windows from changing DHCP Reservation Names

Tags: dhcp-server

It is a SBS-2011 Server. I will create a new DHCP reservation and set the reservation name to "GSMPC-11 N". Then it looks like when it goes active Windows changes the name to the computername.domain i.e. gsmpc-11.gsmetalinc.com

Well..... what is the point in even creating a reservation name when Windows changes it to computername.domain automatically? Is there any way to stop it from changing the reservation name?

See attached screen shot.....[image]

Comment: AFAIK a hostname can't contain blanks. So the DHCP services changes the name into something valid.

Comment: If you look at say GSMPC-03 there are no spaces in that yet Windows changed it to GSMPC-03.gsmetalinc.com. I have changed a couple back with no spaces to see what happens but won't hold my breath. Other responses I have gotten simply says thats just the way it is.....

Comment: I went back and re-did some without spaces. No difference. Windows changed them.